# Почему растягивается background?

Tags: android

требуется вывести вертикальный текст на картинке

воспользовался этим вариантом для реализации вертикального **TextView**

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/verticaltextview.php

```
public class VerticalTextView extends TextView {
    final boolean topDown;

    public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        final int gravity = getGravity();
        if (Gravity.isVertical(gravity)
            && (gravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
            setGravity((gravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK)
                | Gravity.TOP);
            topDown = false;
        } else {
            topDown = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)         {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
        textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
        textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();

        canvas.save();

        if (topDown) {
            canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
            canvas.rotate(90);
        } else {
            canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
            canvas.rotate(-90);
        }

        canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());

        getLayout().draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Столкнулся с проблемой:

если у TextView задать цвет фона то текст выводится на цветном прямоугольнике

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <test.VerticalTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:background="#00FF00" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если фоном задать изображение то оно деформируется, получая ширину равной длине надписи. Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. исходная картинка для background'а имеет такую же ширину как и зеленая полоска на первой картинке

**добавил:**

в предлагаемом варианте вертикального TextView область вывода становиться квадратной, а так как для bitmap свойство gravity = fill фон деформируется

вопрос: как усечь ширину области вывода до высоты шрифта, так чтоб область была не квадратной, а прямоугольной как на этом изображении?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно ли переопределить методы родительского класса, так чтоб ширина и высота TextView были равны исходному фоновому изображению?

Comment: Попробуй поставить TextView атрибут 
adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: @alex11, не помогло (

Comment: Исходная картинка - такой же ширины, как и зеленая полоса.  А какой она высоты?  Возможно, она просто растягивается на всю высоту текста - и пропорционально растягивается в ширину.

Comment: @AleksG, размеры исходной картинки 22х65px, размер зеленой подложки 30х54px. Мне кажется, что картинка растягивается до ширины текста в горизонтальном положении. Но не понимаю как это исправить.